# How to add float values from array in for-loop in Jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm quite new to Python, so it's highely likely that my thinking is flawed on this matter. But I thought it would be quite simple to add some values together in a for-loop in a Jinja2 template. Due to reasons unknown to me, it can't be done with my rudimentair knowledge of this language. I hope you lot can help me with this.

I have an array with some floats in Python:

`floatArray = [1.5,3.6,5.8,9.8,10,5.0]`

I pass that array through in my template:

`render_template("array.html", floatArray=floatArray,)`

In my template I want to add these values together:

```
{% set total = 0.0 %}
        
{% for x in floatArray %}
    {% set total = x + total %}
    {{ x }} - {{ total }}<br>
{% endfor %}
<br>{{ total }}
```

This is the result I get:

```
1.5 - 1.5
3.6 - 3.6
5.8 - 5.8
9.8 - 9.8
10 - 10.0
5.0 - 5.0

0.0
```

What I expect is that the second column of the values will add up with the previous ones: 1.5, 5.1, 10.9, etc. The last number should be the total sum of the values: 35.7

For some reason the value of {{total}} resets itself after every iteration. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Of course I can use:

```
{{ float_array|sum() }}
```

But that won't be sufficient. I have several for loops in my code and I want to sum parts of those loops.

Please kick me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` statement creates a new scope in Jinja2. You can create a [`namespace`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#assignments) variable instead to allow access to the variable from an inner scope:

```
{% set ns = namespace(total=0.0) %}
{% for x in floatArray %}
    {% set ns.total = x + ns.total %}
    {{ x }} - {{ ns.total }}<br>
{% endfor %}
<br>{{ ns.total }}
```

Comment: Finally! That was almost the solution. The only problem I encountered was the inaccuracy of the float type and since I use these values to add currency values, I've made decimals of the numbers in my Python script:
floatArray = [Decimal('1.5'), Decimal('3.6'), Decimal('5.8'), Decimal('9.8'), Decimal('10'), Decimal('5.0')]